# How to select count where time between a list of date ranged?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table named "record".

```
userid | date
------ | ------
1      | 2017-08-21  
1      | 2017-08-22  
2      | 2017-08-22  
1      | 2017-08-23  
3      | 2017-08-23
```

Now I need three SQL to count userid.

```
select count(DISTINCT userid) from record where date between 2017-08-21  and 2017-08-23;
```

result : 3

```
select count(DISTINCT userid) from record where date between 2017-08-22  and 2017-08-23;
```

result : 3

```
select count(DISTINCT userid) from record where date between 2017-08-23  and 2017-08-23;
```

result : 2

I want count those by one time, Could someone help me with this please ?

Comment: I don't understand. What is the result you're trying to get?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. What does "I want count those by one time" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct date_field,
       (select count(distinct userid) from record r1 where r1.date_field between r2.date_field and '2017-08-23')
  FROM record r2
```

Or this more efficient version suggested by Shelden

```
SELECT date_field,
       (select count(distinct userid) from record r1 where r1.date_field between r2.date_field and '2017-08-23')
  FROM (select distinct date_field from record) r2
```

Comment: ... FROM (SELECT distinct date_field FROM record) r2; more efficient

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select count(distinct case when between '2017-08-21' and '2017-08-23' then userid end),
       count(distinct case when between '2017-08-22' and '2017-08-23' then userid end),
       count(distinct case when between '2017-08-24' and '2017-08-23' then userid end)
from record r;
```